# Android's recent apps list redirecting to another app

Tags: android

I have code in an App (let'call it app 'A') that starts an activity on a second app (let's call it app 'B') when the user clicks a button.

So far so good but I'd expect to later be able go back to app 'A' using the system's overview screen (aka recent apps list), but when I try to I'm redirected back to App B automatically, as if I was clicking the button a second time.

The phone is running Android KitKat and the code looks like this:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.some.package.MAIN"));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Android remembers exactly where the user was when they switch tasks.  This is normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far so good but I'd expect to later be able go back to app 'A' using the system's overview screen (aka recent apps list), but when I try to I'm redirected back to App B automatically, as if I was clicking the button a second time.

This is the default behaviour of Android.
Android Activity life cycle uses a context based statck called [**Task**.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
So the App 'B' is simply inside the the Task of calling Activity App 'A'.

**You can override this behaviour by using the following flag.**

```
  mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Intent i=new Intent("com.some.package.MAIN");                    
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                    
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

**1) FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** - If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack. A task (from the activity that started it to the next task activity) defines an atomic group of activities that the user can move to. Tasks can be moved to the foreground and background; all of the activities inside of a particular task always remain in the same order.

**2) FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** - If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

**3) FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** - If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: Thank you. Well I can see uses for such "default" behavior but it would be nice to be able to overcome/bypass this somehow. If I'm not starting the second activity for a result, then there should be some way I can go back to the first - other than using the  back button, that is - otherwise it will be forever lost in interface limbo, sight

Comment: I'm new to SO, should I wait a couple days for a proposed fix/suggestion and if I don't get it I will mark  you answer as the right answer, would that be the proper way to go?

Comment: btw, maybe something that would work  would be would be to get  app B to keep track of whether it was initiated by  another app and override it's onResume so it o order to pop itself from the stack. But it looks very dirty to me to have to modify app B for this to work.

Comment: Just add this flag, thats enough. :)                     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);